Your Bitcoin was successfully turned into USD.Requesting your agreement.. Transaction IDXXXXXXXXX
my email is full of request about bitcoin Bing transferred into US dollar. requesting my authorization and it has a link and a whole bunch of wallet partial wallet addresses talking about. This is where Bitcoin is coming from, but and it's funded or ready for my account, but I'm not aware of the account that I set up to have these funds transferred to. I do recall a time ago where I had set up a. two wallets on two different crypto exchanges and I had bought crypto. This is way back in like 2000 or something. since then I lost my keys to both wallets as we didn't really understand what was going on and the longevity of everything. But now that you know I've had to shut down two emails regarding the stuff I've know that I think I might have been A victim theft by fraud. can someone give me some direction?
